# creating a check for a loop in driver

Tags: mips

I created code for a procedure that outputs the factoral of a number given. But it needs to ask the user for a number until they enter a negative before it exits.

So that it looks something like this

Enter a value for n (or a negative value to exit): 6

6! is 720

Enter a value for n (or a negative value to exit): 9

9! is 362880

Enter a value for n (or a negative value to exit): 11

11! is 39916800

Enter a value for n (or a negative value to exit): 20

20! is -2102132736

Enter a value for n (or a negative value to exit): 100

100! is 0

Enter a value for n (or a negative value to exit): -1

Thanks for Testing!

Instead of something like this.

Enter the value of a number (or negative to exit): 5

Value returned is 120

Thanks for testing!

```
fact:   
slti    $t0, $a0, 1     # test for n < 1
beq $t0, $zero, L1  # if n >= 1, go to L1

li  $v0, 1      # return 1
jr  $ra     # return to instruction after jal

L1: 
addi $sp, $sp, -8   # adjust stack for 2 items
sw  $ra, 4($sp) # save the return address
sw  $a0, 0($sp) # save the argument n

addi    $a0, $a0, -1    # n >= 1; argument gets (n – 1)
jal fact        # call fact with (n – 1)

lw  $a0, 0($sp) # return from jal: restore argument n
lw  $ra, 4($sp) # restore the return address
addi    $sp, $sp, 8 # adjust stack pointer to pop 2 items

mul $v0, $a0, $v0   # return n * fact (n – 1)

jr  $ra     # return to the caller

main:
la  $a0, nreq   # get value of n
li  $v0, 4
syscall

li  $v0, 5      # read value of n 
syscall
move $a0, $v0       # place value n in $a0
jal fact        # invoke fact

move $s0, $v0       #save value returned by facts

la $a0, ans     # display
li  $v0, 4
syscall

move $a0, $s0
li $v0, 1
syscall

la  $a0, cr     #display closing 
li  $v0, 4
syscall

li  $v0, 10     # exit
syscall

.data
```

nreq:   .asciiz "Enter a value for n (or negative to exit): "
ans:    .asciiz "Value returned is "
cr: .asciiz "\nThanks for testing!\n"

Answer (score 0):

Overall, pretty close. However, one or two things.

I'd move `main` to the top, above `fact`, as some simulators start at the lowest `.text` address rather than the given symbol `main`. For example, in `mars`, this didn't seem to work until I reversed the order.

`main` was missing the test for negative input and didn't loop on itself.

Here's a version that seems to work [please pardon the gratuitous style cleanup]:

```
    .text
    .globl  main
main:
    la      $a0,nreq                # get value of n
    li      $v0,4
    syscall

    li      $v0,5                   # read value of n
    syscall

# NOTE/BUG: add this
    bltz    $v0,exit                # exit program on negative

    move    $a0,$v0                 # place value n in $a0
    jal     fact                    # invoke fact

    move    $s0,$v0                 # save value returned by facts

    la      $a0,ans                 # display
    li      $v0,4
    syscall

    move    $a0,$s0
    li      $v0,1
    syscall

# NOTE: add this
    li      $v0,4
    la      $a0,nl
    syscall
    j       main

exit:
    la      $a0,cr                  # display closing
    li      $v0,4
    syscall

    li      $v0,10                  # exit
    syscall

fact:
    slti    $t0,$a0,1               # test for n < 1
    beq     $t0,$zero,L1            # if n >= 1, go to L1

    li      $v0,1                   # return 1
    jr      $ra                     # return to instruction after jal

L1:
    addi    $sp,$sp,-8              # adjust stack for 2 items
    sw      $ra,4($sp)              # save the return address
    sw      $a0,0($sp)              # save the argument n

    addi    $a0,$a0,-1              # n >= 1; argument gets (n – 1)
    jal     fact                    # call fact with (n – 1)

    lw      $a0,0($sp)              # return from jal: restore argument n
    lw      $ra,4($sp)              # restore the return address
    addi    $sp,$sp,8               # adjust stack pointer to pop 2 items

    mul     $v0,$a0,$v0             # return n * fact (n – 1)

    jr      $ra                     # return to the caller

    .data
nreq:       .asciiz     "Enter a value for n (or negative to exit): "
ans:        .asciiz     "Value returned is "
nl:         .asciiz     "\n"
cr:         .asciiz     "\nThanks for testing!\n"
```